# How can I get all pipeline elements at a time?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.3, powershell-7

I created this very simple PowerShell script:

```
using namespace System.IO

[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
param
(
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)][FileInfo[]]$Files
)
$Files.Length
$Files | Sort-Object | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}
```

When I call it with any result of a `Get-ChildItem` call, `$Files.Length` is always `1`, no matter how many files are in a directory:

```
PS C:\Temp> Get-ChildItem -File C:\Windows\ | .\Rename-Test.ps1
1
WMSysPr9.prx
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: your script is missing a `process` block :) otherwise you would see only the last item coming from the pipeline cause the default is `end` block

Comment: Oh, gee!! I didn't know a script block was required for the script root, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @SantiagoSquarzon. Do you want to convert your comment into an answer? I'd be happy to upvote.

Comment: I can yeah but I'm missing some clarification, I see you're looking to `Sort-Object` however in a `process` block you have one at a time processing so no sorting is possible. Are you looking to collect all input from the pipeline to then sort it?

Comment: Yes, indeed. And after few more tests I now know I won't be able to use the pipeline for my purpose. I need to call `Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object` from within my script and accept `Filter`, `SourcePath` and other `Get-ChildItem` parameters in my script to apply these within the script. – However, I still would like to accept your answer as it may be helpful to others.

Comment: Not really, there is always a way. You could use a `List<T>` to collect all input in the `process` block then work in with that collected input in your `end` block :)

Comment: Gee, awesome! Sure, that's a great idea! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your script is only missing a [`process` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#process) otherwise, the [default block is `end`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#end) thus you would be only seeing the last element coming from the pipeline. A minimal example of how you can approach it:

```bash
using namespace System.IO

[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact = 'High')]
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [FileInfo[]] $Files
)

process {
    foreach($file in $Files) {
        if($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($file.Name, 'Doing something')) {
            $file.FullName
        }
    }
}
```

As you may note, since the `-Files` parameter is typed `[FileInfo[]]` (array of `FileInfo` instances), a loop is required in case the argument is passed via [named parameter or positionally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#parameter-position).

If however you need to collect all input, i.e. for sorting it, then you would be needing a [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0) to collect each object in the `process` block and then work with the collected input in the `end` block, for example:

```
using namespace System.IO

[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [FileInfo[]] $Files
)

begin {
    $items = [System.Collections.Generic.List[FileInfo]]::new()
}
process {
    $items.AddRange($Files)
}
end {
    $items | Sort-Object Length
}
```

Then for the above, both ways would work fine:

```bash
# from pipeline
Get-ChildItem -File | .\myscript.ps1

# from positional binding
.\myscript.ps1 (Get-ChildItem -File)
```